# How can I reuse arrays in a plist file in Xcode?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, plist

I created the following property list (.plist) file in Xcode.
It is a Shared App Group Watch Settings Bundle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ApplicationGroupContainerIdentifier</key>
    <string>group.com....</string>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Primary Colors</string>
            <key>key</key>
            <string>primColors</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>Black</string>
            <key>Values</key>
            <array>
                <string>Black</string>
                <string>White</string>
                <string>Blue</string>
                <string>Red</string>
                <string>Yellow</string>
                <string>...</string>
            </array>
            <key>Titles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Black</string>
                <string>White</string>
                <string>Blue</string>
                <string>Red</string>
                <string>Yellow</string>
                <string>...</string>
            </array>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>primColors_preference</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Secondary Colors</string>
            <key>key</key>
            <string>secColors</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>White</string>
            <key>Values</key>
            <array>
                <string>Black</string>
                <string>White</string>
                <string>Blue</string>
                <string>Red</string>
                <string>Yellow</string>
                <string>...</string>
            </array>
            <key>Titles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Black</string>
                <string>White</string>
                <string>Blue</string>
                <string>Red</string>
                <string>Yellow</string>
                <string>...</string>
            </array>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>secColor_preference</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

As you can see I have two Multi Value Elements, Primary Colors and Secondary Colors (will be a long list of colors). Each setting has two arrays, one for the Titles key and the other for Values key.

In my case these Titles and Values arrays as you can see will be exactly the same. In total I have four arrays that are exactly the same this way. If it is possible how can I create one main array (that I can adjust) and reuse it in the other arrays?

I want this so when I modify the main array the other arrays will be modified as well.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why this has to be a plist file and not a swift struct?

Comment: @gmogames The plist file creates a auto generated settings page in the watch app. I don’t know if you can do that with a struct?